# How do I put the current GIT branch in the warfile manifest of an Ant project

Tags: git, ant, branch, manifest

We have both Maven and Ant projects.

I've managed to do this with maven jar files using org.codehaus.mojo buildnumber-maven-plugin (unfortunately the same method doesn't work for war files).

However the main question is how to do this with ant in build.xml

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
<target name="war">
<exec executable="git" outputproperty="branch" failonerror="false">
    <arg value="rev-parse"/>
    <arg value="--abbrev-ref"/>
    <arg value="HEAD"/>
</exec>
<manifest>
    <attribute name="Build-Branch" value="${branch}"/>
</manifest>
```

...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).